# Association rules syntax for rhs for multiple values

Tags: r, associations, rules

While using appearance function in *a priori*, how can we pass more than 3 values in rhs? E.g.

```
appreance=list(c(rhs="survived=yes=, "survived=no")))
```

But if we have too much values of survived then how can we pass the all values? I need to add values myself or there is any other way to call all values?

Comment: What language are you using? Your question isn't very clear at the moment

Comment: I am using R Programming.

Comment: Hi @JakubJankowski ,,,,,,,basket_rules <- apriori(txn,parameter = list(support = 0.01, confidence =0.5),appearance = list(rhs=c(AssigneeRealName="Martin Aeschlimann",AssigneeRealName="Adam Archer",AssigneeRealName="Ayushman Jain",AssigneeRealName="Andre Weinand",AssigneeRealName="Dorian Birsan",AssigneeRealName="Aaron Ferguson",AssigneeRealName="Abhishek Kishore",AssigneeRealName="Achim Demelt",),default="lhs"), control = list(verbose=F))
In AssigneeRealName I need to enter the all assignee names manually or is there any shortcut to get all the names from the attribute ??